# jQuery JSON parse - "Object not defined"

Tags: php, jquery, json

Currently working for the first time with JSON and with little experience of jQuery.
I have this function that gets triggered on "success" of $.ajax request:

```
function(data) {

    $.each(data.notifications, function(notifications) {
        alert('New Notification!');
    });

}
```

However I get an error in the firebug console stating "object is undefined" "length = object.length".

The JSON response is:

```
["notifications",[["test would like to connect with you",{"Accept":"\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=accept","Decline":"\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=decline"}]]]
```

I guess it has something to do with the number of `[]`s but the JSON was encoded by PHP using json_encode()

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a JSON Array. I'm guessing you were looking for something like this:

```
{
    "notifications": [
        ["test would like to connect with you",
        {
            "Accept": "\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=accept",
            "Decline": "\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=decline"
        }]
    ]
}
```

Although I think a better structure would be:

```
{
    "notifications": [
        {
            "message": "test would like to connect with you",
            "Accept": "\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=accept",
            "Decline": "\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=decline"
        }
    ]
}
```

This way `notification` becomes a property of the object, which means you can access it via `data.notifications`. Otherwise you'd have to access the notifications via `data[1]` (`data[0]` would contain the string "notifications" which essentially becomes meaningless).

The following example should give you an idea as far as setting up your data in PHP:

```
<?php
  $array = array(
      "notifications" => array(
          array(
              "message" => "Test would like to connect with you",
              "Accept" => "/events/index.php/user/connection?userId=20625101&action=accept",
              "Decline" => "/events/index.php/user/connection?userId=20625101&action=decline"
          )
      )
  );

  echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP response should actually be:

```
{
    "notifications": [
       ["test would like to connect with you",
        {
           "Accept":"\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=accept",
           "Decline":"\/events\/index.php\/user\/connection?userId=20625101&action=decline"
        }
       ]
    ]
}
```

Note that with the above, `notification` is a field inside the object that the string represents. That will allow you to iterate, the way you are doing it with `$.each(..)`.

---

The way you are doing is it by having an array (note the initial `[` and the last `]` in the response). The error is because `$.each` invokes `data.notification.length` where `.length` is an operation on undefined.

---

PHP side code should be somewhat like below:

```
echo json_encode(array("notifications" => $notifications));
```

instead of (my guess):

```
echo json_encode(array("notification", $notifications));
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why my json_encode($array) is returning a JSON array rather than object?

Comment: thanks for your help! I've figured out why it was giving JSON array - because I wasn't supplying name=>value pairs in array. Used to C and Java arrays :)